# Converting 'YYYY mmm DD' character format to date in R

Tags: r, date

I'm scraping some data off the web, which it reads in as a list.  I convert to a dataframe, and then all the data is read as factors.  I am able to convert the date factors, displayed as (example) "2008 Feb 02" to characters, but at this point it is such an awkward format, the 'as.date' function fails to read in the characters as dates.
Any ideas here?

Comment: you can look at the doc for `strptime`, in your cast `strptime(your_data,format="%Y %b %d")` should work

Comment: just a side remark: If you do not want your data to be read as factors when converting to data frame, try specifiying `stringsAsFactors=F` to you `[as.]data.frame` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have something like this:

```r
df<-data.frame(some_column=c('A', 'B', 'C')
              ,some_other_column=c('1', '2', '3')
              ,date=c("2008 Feb 02", "1970 Jan 01", "2015 Feb 15") 
              ,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
str(df)
```

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ some_column      : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ some_other_column: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ date             : Factor w/ 3 levels "1970 Jan 01",..: 2 1 3
```

So far you managed to do something like this:

```r
date.chr<-as.character(df$date)
str(date.chr)
```

```
chr [1:3] "2008 Feb 02" "1970 Jan 01" "2015 Feb 15"
```

What you actually want to do may be something like this:

```r
date<-strptime(date.chr, format="%Y %b %d")
str(date)
```

```
POSIXlt[1:3], format: "2008-02-02" "1970-01-01" "2015-02-15"
```

Or, to combine and shorten the above:

```r
df$date<-strptime(df$date, "%Y %b %d")
str(df)
```

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ some_column      : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ some_other_column: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ date             : POSIXlt, format: "2008-02-02" "1970-01-01" "2015-02-15"
```

See `?strptime` for a detailed documentation of the `format` option.

*edit:*

As pointed out by [BondedDust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677), `as.Date` also supports the `format` option and would be much more appropriate in the context of data frame due to the list nature of `POSIXlt`.

So this solution is definitely preferable:

```r
df$date<-as.Date(df$date, "%Y %b %d")
str(df)
```

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ some_column      : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ some_other_column: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ date             : Date, format: "2008-02-02" "1970-01-01" "2015-02-15"
```